# Java net.Url Library doesn't connect in linux terminal

Tags: java, linux, url, terminal

I was trying some codes with Java net.Url library and I can't seem to make the example codes works, the URL variable is null while the url I'm trying to connect does have information.

the code throws this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at WebAddresses.main(WebAddresses.java:20)
```

Can't make it work, firewall is off and have tried in Linux Mint 18.3 and Windows 10 (same computer).

Comment: could you show some of the code you are using? specifically line 20 of your WebAddresses class

Comment: a No Such Element Exception is: "Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist"

Comment: It's and example and have tried with a lot of them, shouldn't be a problem the code, It's this code from Programming by Doing http://programmingbydoing.com/a/examples/WebAddresses.java

Comment: did you copy it exactly?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what could it be, doesn't work in Linux and Windows either. I'm guessing maybe something with the router, I have and Arris DG1660 don't know if that helps, and I'm using the Terminal en both OS to execute the code.

Comment: could you post the code that you are using exactly as you have it? just in cased you missed something

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something does not work in Linux while it actually should, my first suspicion is that the user's account lacks some rights required. Did you try to run your code as root experimetally?

Comment: No luck, plus also doesn't work in Windows, I'm guessing something with the router maybe, but still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the resource you are trying to access actually exists. If it does, please post the code you use. Without the code it will be impossible to determine what the problem actually is.